# Bordes en etiqueta HTML

Tags: html, css

tengo que hacer el borde de Learn more y por cómo lo estoy haciendo no queda igual, debería quedar así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

(el color de fondo da igual, luego pongo el correcto)

Lo estaba intentando hacer con border radius pero creo que no es correcto, llevo esto

```
.learn2{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: turquoise;
    width: 12rem;
    height: 4rem;
    border-radius: 45%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas bien, solo debes modificar lo siguiente:

- El `border-radius` establecelo por ejemplo en pixeles y no en porcentajes
- No hace falta el uso de flex, con encerrar el texto por ejemplo en un span y a ese elemento por ejemplo darle un margin lograrás que se separe de su contenedor padre y de todos modos quede centrado vertical y horizontalmente
- Usa `outline` con un valor de `none` para lograr que el efecto al darle click desaparezca
- Usa a `border` con un valor de `none` para quitar la línea de borde que le aparece

```html
      <style>
      .learn2{
        background-color: turquoise;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 20px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        outline: none;
        padding: 10px;
    } 
        span {
          margin: 20px;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button class="learn2">
      <span>
          LEARN MORE
      </span>
    </button>
```